# Is it rare for a language to contain both heterographs and heteronyms?

Tags: orthography, pronunciation, homonymy, homophony

English has many heterographs: words that are spelled differently but pronounced the same. Examples include *there*/*their*/*they're*, *hear*/*here*, *red*/*read*, *led*/*lead*, etc.

English also has heteronyms: words that are spelled the same but pronounced differently. Examples include *wind* (blow/rotate), *bow* (tie/bend), *lead* (manage/metal), *read*, etc.

Is it rare for a language to have both of these concepts? Does English have more examples than other languages?

Comment: For heteronyms, does it count if the words are only different in stress or tone? There are many languages where stress and tone patterns are not written.

Comment: @sumelic yes I'd say that counts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on how we define the terms, I think heteronyms are quite commonly present in writing systems. Heterographs are also often present to some degree. So I would say no, it is not rare at all for a writing system to have both. (This is really a feature of a specific writing system for a language, not of a language by itself). These phenomena may occur less frequently in most other languages compared to English, but they are usually present.

### In non-alphabetic writing systems

In many non-alphabetic writing systems, such as those of Chinese and Japanese, heterographs are quite common. These languages also have heteronyms (here's a [Reddit post with a list of some Mandarin Chinese heteronyms](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage/comments/1jekci/does_anyone_have_a_good_list_of_mandarin/).)

### Heteronyms in alphabetic writing systems

(I'm using the term "alphabetic" broadly to include consonant-oriented systems like those used for most Semitic languages, or syllable-oriented systems like those used for most Indic languages.) I think the most common source of heteronyms is a systematic under-specification of some contrast in the language's sound system. For example, for many languages, stress and tone patterns are not written, but may be contrastive between otherwise identical different words. I would consider words like this heteronyms, but some people might disagree.

In any case, another common area of underspecification is the representation of vowels. In languages like German and English, vowel "length" (which has changed around a bit in English) is only marked indirectly, so there are some ambiguous cases (like *wind* in English). Contrastive vowel length is often not marked when writing Latin (although it is possible to do so with diacritics), leading to heteronyms like *malum* (with a long a, "apple"; with a short a, "an evil thing"). According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel_length#Notations_in_other_writing_systems), contrastive vowel length was also not marked in some contexts in Ancient Greek writing and Korean Hangul, so there may have been heteronyms relating to length in these languages.

Vowel quality may also be underspecified. It seems to me that this is fairly common in African languages, some of which have large vowel inventories. For example, in the [writing system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sotho_orthography#Limitations) of the [Sotho language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sotho_phonology#Stress) (Sesotho), the letter *e* represents three distinct vowel qualities, /ɪ/, /e/, and /ɛ/, and *o* represents /ʊ/, /o/, and /ɔ/. Tone is also contrastive, and not written, and according to Wikipedia there is at least one minimal pair for stress:

> the adverb *fela* ('only') [ˈfɛlɑ] has regular stress, while the
>   conjunctive *fela* ('but') [fɛˈlɑ] (like many other conjunctives) has
>   stress on the final syllable.

So we can see some degree of heteronymy is commonly present in writing systems from the very beginning.

### Heterographs in alphabetic writing systems

Generally, someone designing (consciously or just through use) a new alphabetic writing system does not plan on including heterographs. However, there are a few processes that naturally cause them to arise.

Sound changes: That's one of the main causes in English. If two sounds merge in some context, you're likely to get heterographs (such as *you're, your, yore*). Generally, these accumulate over time, so an older writing system will have more of them. In some cases, heterographs are present from the beginning for some speakers due to variation between different accents of the language (some accents may have a merger that doesn't exist in others, and the writing system is based on the un-merged accent).

Loanwords: It's possible for all loanwords to be re-spelled according to the borrowing language's writing system. However, there are many languages like English that tend to preserve the original spelling. This may cause heterographs.

Comment: Wow thanks for the great answer. And thanks for pointing out my oversight that the phenomenon is really only relevant to writing systems and not the language in and of itself.

Comment: Heteronyms differentiated by stress patterns also exist in English, e.g. (the) record/(to) record

Answer (score 2):

Heterographs, as you call them, are pretty common. German uses spelling to differentiate word pars like Lerche/Lärche, Lied/Lid, fiel/viel, mehr/Meer, Mohr/Moor, mahlen/malen; French differentiates a/à, ou/où, etc.

Heteronyms, as you call them, also occur in other languages, German has the nice doublet Montage (Mondays/assembly, installation, mounting). German also has some ambiguous compounds like Wachstube (Wach-Stube or Wachs-Tube) or Staubecken (Stau-Becken or Staub-Ecken).

I think specially heteronyms are more frequent in English than in any other language I know. This has to do with the age of the established orthography and the on-going evolution of the spoken language leading to a gulf between spoken and written language.

Comment: There is also *Weg* vs *weg* in German, but it is rare, and they are different parts of speech, and thus capitalised differently.